# Canonical "My JavaScript isn't working" question for the answer "IDs must be unique"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

Is there a good canonical question we can use to close duplicates of questions ([like this recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610124/jquery-remove-only-works-once-not-working-on-another-div)) that are basically "My JavaScript code doesn't work" to which the answer is "You cannot use the same `id` on multiple elements"?

I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382414/click-each-button-with-the-same-id/1382425#1382425) from 2009, we could edit it to to be canonical (remove the PrototypeJS-specific stuff).

In general, would prefer to edit a real one (like the above) if necessary rather than creating a synthetic one.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8498579/1324033)? Rather than talking about the error it explains what jquery tries to do and why (which I'd imagine is the same for vanillaJS)

Comment: @Sayse: I'd rather avoid one where the question *has* to allow for invalid HTML, as that one apparently does.

Comment: Perhaps that would merit a separate canonical. Perhaps, then, we need two canonicals.

Comment: @BoltClock: :-)